# Linux cmd I do not understand

Tags: bash

I just found the next cmd in a Linux script:

```
(mkdir -p toolchain && cd toolchain && ln -s ${NATIVE_TOOLCHAIN_HOME}/build/* .)
```

I never used parenthesis like this and I believe it creates a folder named toolchain, it goes inside this folder... is it copying the content of `${NATIVE_TOOLCHAIN_HOME}/build/` into toolchain?

Comment: `ln` doesn't copy. `man ln` or `ln --help`.

Comment: The parentheses create a subshell, so that the call to `cd` doesn't change the working directory for later commands that are outside of the parentheses

Comment: Paste your complete command there: https://explainshell.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis create a subshell in bash.

So you're creating a subshell that executes 3 commands in a row whenever the previous one is successfull:

1. Creates a folder
2. Enters in that folder
3. Executes the `ln`

When it finishes, you're not located in that folder, because all those commands were executed in the subshell.

You can see more in the `man bash`:

> Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the  shell's  environment do  not  remain  in effect after the command completes.  The return status is the exit status of list.